# Navigate between tabs using the back button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to create my first Xamarin mobile application, I am a bit confused when it comes to navigating back to the previous screen/tab using the back button (android). I have created a test project and I am using Xamarin form shell to define the hierarchy.
The navigation type I am using is Tab. In my test application I got 2 tabs

This is my current method which I am using to navigate back to the first tab from the second tab if the user presses on the back button.
I override OnBackButtonPressed method and execute a command that executes GoTo method.

```cs
    public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
        {
            ItemsViewModel _viewModel;
            public ICommand goBack; 
            public ItemsPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = _viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
                goBack = new Command(async (x) => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("////AboutPage"));
            }
            protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                _viewModel.OnAppearing();           
            }
            protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
            {
                base.OnBackButtonPressed();
                goBack.Execute(null);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

This works, but the problem is, I have hardcoded the page I wanna go back to. In the future, I will be adding 2 more tabs, so in that case say for example if the user is on the 4th tab and the previous tab was Tab 3, how can I retrieve that information so that I can successfully navigate the user back to that previous tab or page?
I tried to use the navigationstack in the Shell but couldn't figure out how to use it with tabs.

Thank you for your time.

Cheers

Edit

-Code in the AppShell which defines the hierarchy

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp03.Views"
           Title="TestApp03"
           x:Class="TestApp03.AppShell">
        <TabBar>
            <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        </TabBar>
    </Shell>
```

Comment: Why are you overriding the back button - what happens, if you don't override? What is the XAML you wrote to define the set of tabs as part of Shell's hierarchy? Or for a simple set of tabs, maybe use `TabbedPage` instead of Shell.

Comment: If I don't override the backbutton, it closes the app on pressing the back button. I will post the code which shows the hierarchy in the shell. I am thinking of just using tabbedpage too instead of Shell. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");` to achieve forward jump. For more usage, please refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs

Comment: Hi Wen, 
thanks for that mate, however, what I am trying to do is have the backwards navigation.
Cheers

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your statement. After the user jumped from the third page to the fourth page, if he wants to return to the third page, he can use the above statement.